# h:message doesn't catch message. validation for dataTable, jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have an issue with message rendering for dataTable with dynamic columns. 
I want message to be shown above the datatable but there are some troubles with ids.

```
<h:form id="formId">

<!-- Here the jsf has to recognize id column_0 but it doesn't-->
   <h:message  styleClass="validationError"  for="column_0" />
   <rich:dataTable id="priorityTable" value="#{bean.matrix}" var="priority">
        <rich:columns value="#{bean.ordersOrigin}"
                                      var="ordersOrigin"
                                      index="ind">
           <f:facet name="header">
               <h:outputText value="#{ordersOrigin}" />
           </f:facet>
        <!-- Here i have ids from column_0 to column_2-->
           <h:inputText value="#{priority[ind].value}" id="column_#{ind}">
               <f:validator validatorId="priorityValueValidator"/>
           </h:inputText>
        <!-- Line * -->
        </rich:columns>
  </rich:dataTable>
  <br/>
  <a4j:commandButton value="Apply" action="#{bean.apply}" reRender="formId"/>

</h:form>
```

The problem is that h:message doesn't catch the message. But if i put the same in 'Line *' everything works but looks very ugly.

It seems to be really easy to solve. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Have you try with rich:messages tag ?

Comment: Yes I did, it works fine. But i think it's not really good praxis to use h:messages because it catches all messages from page and it's needed to add lots of extra checks. I just think that i may miss something with using h:message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a4j:commandButton, so it's better to use the richfaces tag for message.

Rich:messages work fine for your case. Use it ;)

Comment: ok, thanks. I changed to messages and added extra check. it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think root cause of problem is for="column_0" and id="column_#{ind}" does not match.

To check it.

Change

```
   <h:message  styleClass="validationError"  for="column_0" />
```

to

```
   <h:messages/>
```

and see if it catches any message.

If any message appears, note it's id to check against your components id.

EDIT: **Try not to use under score "_" in your id tag.**

### FROM JBOSS DOC

**Note:**

Since 3.3.0GA  requires explicit definition of "id" for children components to ensure that decode process works properly. The example of how you can define unique "id" for children component:

```
<rich:columns value="#{bean.columns}" var="col" index="ind" ... >

        <h:inputText id="input#{ind}" value="">

                <a4j:support id="support#{ind}" event="onchange" reRender="someId" />

        </h:inputText>

</rich:columns>
```

Only if "id" defined as shown above Ajax after onchange event will be processed as expected.

Comment: I have checked it and they match. When i will be sure that everything works for column_0 i'll do the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has being posted a long time ago, I just saw an workaround wrapping h:message within a4j:outputPanel and adding ajaxRendered = true tag attribute. It worked flawlessly in my project.

According to the post I read, the reason for that is, for a Ajax JSF content, when jsf is first loaded, it doesn't recognize the h:message component. Doing as suggested the a4j:outputPanel inserts non-present child components in the component tree. Regarding ajaxRendered attribute, the reason for use it is because it sets the outputPanel (with all its child components) to be rendered with the new values after each AJAX request processing.